# Is the total variation function uniform continuous or continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, bounded-variation

I have been doing some excercises on total variation when the following questions came up to my mind:

(1) Let $f$ be continuous on the interval $[0,1]$ and be of bounded variation. Is it true that its total vatiation function $TV(f_{[0,x]})$ is uniformly continuous? i.e. Is it true that for $\forall\space\epsilon>0$, $\exists\space\delta>0$, such that for arbitrary interval $[a,b]$ with $|b-a|<\delta$, we have $TV(f_{[a,b]})<\epsilon$?

(2) Alternatively, if it is not *uniformly* continuous, can I say that for $\forall\space{}x\in[0,1]\text{ and } \forall\space\epsilon>0$ , $\exists\space\text{ nondegenerate interval }I \text{ such that }x\in{}I\text{ and } TV(f_{I})<\epsilon$?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: What is the total variation function of a monotonous function?

Comment: @Didier I think it should be the absolute value of the difference of end point values? But I still don't see how I can use that on this question...

Comment: Hence, for example, if $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is nondecreasing and if $g(x)=$TV$(f_{[0,x]})$, then $g=\ldots$

Comment: @Didier yeah in that case $g$ would be continuous. Hmm but sorry if I'm getting your point really slow here, I did not assume f is monotone in the question. Are you saying that I should use Jordan's decomposition and express it as the difference of two such functions? But I think that way I will get an inequality instead of an equality and there's no guarantee they are continuous any more

Comment: This shows is that the regularity of  $x\mapsto$TV$(f_{[0,x]})$ is at most the regularity of $f$, in general.

Comment: An idea could be the following: write, assuming that $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=\int_0^x\widetilde f(t)dt$, where $\widetilde f$ is an integrable function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since [a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem), you're actually asking whether the total variation of a continuous function is continuous.

Let $\epsilon\gt0$ and $x_0\in(0,1]$ be given. Since the total variation is non-decreasing, it suffices to find a point $x\lt x_0$ with $TV(f_{[x,x_0]})\lt\epsilon$ to show that the total variation is left-continuous, and thus by symmetry also right-continuous and hence continuous.

Pick some point $x_1\lt x_0$. By  definition there is a partition of $[x_1,x_0]$ such that the sum of absolute differences of function values over the partition is within $\epsilon/2$ of $TV(f_{[x_1,x_0]})$. Since $f$ is continuous, we can find a point $x$ between the last intermediate point of the partition and $x_0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt\epsilon/2$. Refining the partition with this point doesn't decrease its sum of absolute differences. Now the sum of absolute differences in the partition up to $x$ is within $\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$ of $TV(f_{[x_1,x_0]})$, and thus so is $TV(f_{[x_1,x]})$; hence $TV(f_{[x,x_0]})\lt\epsilon$ as required.

Comment: Nice! However, I had hard time understanding the last sentence, so maybe it is worth to supply a few more details as follows:

Let $V$ denote the variation over the partition chosen within $\epsilon/2$ of $TV(f_{[x_1,x_0]})$ as described above. Then
$$TV(f_{[x_1,x_0]})<V+\epsilon/2.$$
Also, $V-|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ is some variation over interval $[x_1,x]$, so we have:
$$TV(f_{[x_1,x]})\ge V-|f(x)-f(x_0)|.$$
Finally, $TV(f_{[x_1,x_0]})=TV(f_{[x_1,x]})+TV(f_{[x,x_0]})$, so that:
$$TV(f_{[x,x_0]}) = TV(f_{[x_1,x_0]}) - TV(f_{[x_1,x]})<(V+\epsilon/2) - (V-|f(x)-f(x_0)|)<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would care to explain the downvote?

Comment: @mathreader actually $V-|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ is *no more than* some variation over $[x_1, x]$. But the proof follows the way you said. +1 for the comment

Comment: @mathreader could you elaborate more on your second inequality?

Comment: @Brofessor, Fiburt: Now I see that there is a little mistake in my comment of 6 years ago. The sentence after the first formula should read: "Also, $V+|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ is some variation over interval $[x_1,x]$...". Indeed, $V$ is some variation over interval $[x_1,x_0]$, and we add to it the difference of values of $f$ on $x_0,x$ and so we get _some_ variation over $[x_1,x]$. So the next formula should read:
$$TV(f_{[x_1,x]})\ge V+|f(x)-f(x_0)|.$$
But of course, $V+|f(x)-f(x_0)|\ge V-|f(x)-f(x_0)|$, so the second inequality is still valid, as is everything after it. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @mathreader thank you i know this post is very old! Since $[x_1,x]\subset[x_1,x_0]$, by virtue of that the overlaping interval add more to the variation sum considered by $V_{[x_1,x_0]}$ over $[x,x_0]$. If i am correct so far, wouldn't that run us the risk of reversing the inequality \begin{align} TV(f_{[x_1,x]})\ge V+|f(x)-f(x_0)|\end{align}? Also, is it true that $[x_1,x_0]\cup[x_0,x]=[x_1,x]$?

Comment: @Brofessor You are right, I mixed up the notation. Let me start anew.

Let $P'=\{x_1,\dots,x_k,x_0\}$ be a partition such that its variation $V'=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}|f(x_j)-f(x_{j+1})|+|f(x_k)-f(x_0)|$ has the property that $TV(f_{[x_1,x_0]})<V'+\epsilon/2$. We refine partition $P'$ by introducing a new point $x$ in between $x_k$ and $x_0$. The new variation $V=V'-|f(x_k)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_k)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|\ge V'$ by the triangle inequality. But now $V-|f(x_0)-f(x)|$ is some variation over $[x_1,x]$, so it is no bigger than the total variation on that interval. Thus, the second inequality holds.

Comment: This answer is fairly misleading. The question as stated refers to the function $G(x) :=  TV(f\vert_{[0,x]})$, so to investigate continuity at the point $x_0$, you should be starting to look at $G(x_0) - G(x)$. You seem to assume a priori that this is the same as $TV(f\vert_{[x,x_0]})$. This step is already not so clear in my opinion.