# Functions of bounded variation and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose that $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function of bounded variation. Define
$g:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = V_a^x f$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $x \in [a, b]$ iff $g$ is continuous at $x$.

The converse is simple. I'm not sure how to prove the forward implication.

I was wondering if 
I could get a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144162/is-the-total-variation-function-uniform-continuous-or-continuous?rq=1