# Continuity of the variation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded variation and continuous.  Then why is it true that the partial variations on intervals $[a, c]$ are continuous in $c$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/144819/28513

Comment: Okay, that's good enough for me thanks.