# the continuity of total variation function of a continuous function of bounded variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions

Let f  be a continuous function of bounded total variation (refer to  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation for the definition) on $[0,1]$, i.e., $\text{Var}_{[0,1]}f<\infty$. Then the total variation  of $f$  on $[0,x]$, denoted by $\text{Var}_{ [0,x]} (f):=V(x)$, is continuous on $[0,1]$. How to prove it? Or any counterexample?

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144162/is-the-total-variation-function-uniform-continuous-or-continuous